# C++ meaning of String^

Tags: .net, string, visual-c++, printing, c++-cli

I'm trying to make a getter for a Label (Windows Form).

In **myForm.h** :

```
public: String^ getLabel1() { return label1->Text; };
```

But when I try to print it, it won't compile!

In **myForm.cpp** :

```
void Main(array<String^>^args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Test::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);

    form.setLabel1();
    std::cout << form.getLabel1() << std::endl;
}
```

I guess I return the wrong type (String^), but i can't find anything on the '^' character, and when I try to return a `std::string`, I can't compile it!
Can someone help me?

Comment: in spite of superficial similarities, this is **not** c++

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`String^` is "Reference to a GC object" - an object that exists in the Managed Heap (i.e. a ".NET object"). Compared to `String*` (a pointer to a `System::String` CLR object or `std::string` (a C++ standard-library string local).

The C++ STL `cout` stream does not support outputting `System::String`, you must either first marshal it to a compatible type, or use `Console::WriteLine` instead.

To re-iterate what sp2danny said in the comments, this is **not** C++, this is C++/CLI, which can be considered a C++-esque syntax for CIL+CLR alternative to C# with the benefit of being able to use existing C++ code in source-form, including the STL.